# How to use only few cops from rubocop-rspec?

Tags: ruby, rspec, rubocop, rubocop-rspec

I would like to use only a few cops from the gem rubocop-rspec.

I've tried this way, but it doesn't work:

```rb
require:
  - rubocop-rspec

RSpec:
  Enabled: false

RSpec/ExampleWithoutDescription:
  Enabled: true
```

I've also tried this:

```rb
require:
  - rubocop-rspec

AllCops:
  RSpec:
    Enabled: false

RSpec/ExampleWithoutDescription:
  Enabled: true
```

Comment: RuboCop has a `DisabledByDefault` setting https://rubocop.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration/ which may help for this.

Answer (score 2):

You can disable all cops by default - as per [the documentation](https://rubocop.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration/#generic-configuration-parameters):

```
AllCops:
  DisabledByDefault: true
```

Answer (score 0):

It should work with something like:

```
require: rubocop-rspec

RSpec:
  Enabled: false
Rspec/ExampleWithoutDescription:
  Enabled: true
```